# React / Redux Child Components not visible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i am new too react / redux and i have a problem with child components. To create a dynamic navigation for a website i've setup a NavigationContainer showing the NavigationComponent and map each item to a NavigationItem component. Unfortunately my actual solution is not working. Can anybody tell me what's missing or wrong?

NavigationContainer.js :

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Navigation from '../components/Navigation'
import NavigationItem from '../components/NavigationItem'
import { getCategories, isCollapsed } from '../reducers/navigation'

const NavigationContainer = ({ title, categories, collapsed }) => (
  <Navigation
    title={title}
    collapsed={collapsed}>
      {categories.map(category =>
        <NavigationItem
          key={category.id}
          nav={category} />
      )}
  </Navigation>
)

NavigationContainer.propTypes = {
  categories: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    link: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  })).isRequired,
  collapsed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  categories: state.navigation.categories,
  collapsed: state.navigation.collapsed,
  title: state.navigation.title
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { }
)(NavigationContainer)
```

Navigation.js :

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { IndexLink, Link } from 'react-router'
import { NavigationItem } from './NavigationItem'

const Navigation = ({ title, collapsed, children }) => {
  const visible = collapsed ? 'active' : ''

  return (
    <div id="wrapper" className={visible}>
      <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <nav id="spy">
          <ul className="sidebar-nav nav">
            <li className="sidebar-brand">
              <Link to="/"><span className="fa fa-home solo">{title}</span></Link>
            </li>
            {children}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

Navigation.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  title: PropTypes.string,
  collapsed: PropTypes.bool
}

export default Navigation
```

NavigationItem.js :

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'

const NavigationItem = ({ nav }) => (
  <li className="sidebar-brand">
    <Link to="/"><span className="fa fa-home solo">{nav.title}</span></Link>
  </li>
)

NavigationItem.propTypes = {
  nav: PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }).isRequired
  //onNavClicked: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default NavigationItem
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is not working exactly? Eg: You are going to the particular route, but the console throws an error xxxx. Also, perhaps you should also add the routes code?

Comment: The mapped categories (NavigationItem) from NavigationContainer are not visible and no error in the console. Here is a dev tools screenshot http://imageshack.com/a/img921/1332/eAqBdy.png

Comment: The only weird thing I see about your code is the `import { NavigationItem } from './NavigationItem'` line in Navigation.js, as 1) `NavigationItem` isn't used in this component, and 2) you are importing it using curly braces, which is inconsistent from your import in NavigationContainer.js.

Comment: A side note but I would recommend passing `categories` to `Navigation` as a prop and letting `Navigation` handle the iteration and creation of `NavigationItem`s. Try that and see if it fixes it?

Comment: @ty-le That way i got it working. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

After Ty Le's recommendation, I rebuilt everything and found that I forgot to import the `Link` from `react-router` in `NavigationItem.js`. That throws an error I've not noticed before. Now everything works.